# What is the difference between using df[col][mask] and df[mask][col]?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is the difference between the following pandas approaches to filtering a DataFrame? (on the [titanic dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data)).

```
df_train['Age'][df_train['Pclass']==1]
df_train[df_train['Pclass']==1]['Age']
```

Comment: Please include some more context. Lists are ordered collections and are not key-value stores like dictionaries. You may be conflating Python lists with some other data structure like PANDAS data-frames.

Comment: you should add a tag for pandas and it seems that you're using pandas dataframes and not lists. 

Also, you're using two filters for subsetting the dataframe both of which will result in same answer because they will work like A ^ B being same as B ^ A; where ^ represents intersection

Comment: the syntax is similar, but `x[y]` is _indexing_, not necessarily working with a list! (in your case, you likely have a [Pandas DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html))

Comment: Oh... Im sorry to ask an inexperienced question. It is first time to use stack overflow... and all of your help are efficient. very thank you.

Comment: @HenryEcker please reinstate your excellent answer. The short answer is "both lines produce the identical result. However both are undesirable for the same reason: slicing twice (needlessly) produces a pandas copy instead of a slice. Copies waste memory and are a bad coding habit. Avoid doing them. Solution: **use `[]`/`.loc` to select from both dimensions at once**: `df_train[df_train['Pclass']==1, 'Age']`

Comment: I removed it because I was unsure if I was missing some obvious issue/obvious duplicate but I was unable to find such. It's reinstated per your request. @smci

Answer (score 0):

They are different paths to the same result.

Let's take some sample data:

```py
df_train = pd.DataFrame({
    'Age': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
    'Pclass': [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
    'Other Col': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'Other Col2': [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
})
```

| Age | Pclass | Other Col | Other Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 1 | 7 |
| 11 | 0 | 2 | 8 |
| 12 | 1 | 3 | 9 |
| 13 | 0 | 4 | 10 |
| 14 | 0 | 5 | 11 |
| 15 | 1 | 6 | 12 |

In the case of:

```py
df_train['Age'][df_train['Pclass'] == 1]
```

We first extract the 'Age' column from the DataFrame (potentially making a copy of the Series):

```py
df_train['Age']

0    10
1    11
2    12
3    13
4    14
5    15
Name: Age, dtype: int64
```

and *then* filter the rows in the selected column based on the boolean index (potentially making another copy):

```py
df_train['Age'][df_train['Pclass'] == 1]

0    10
2    12
5    15
Name: Age, dtype: int64
```

This is the less expensive of the two options since it works within a Series of values.

---

However, in the other case:

```py
df_train[df_train['Pclass']==1]['Age']
```

We first filter *all* of the rows which match the Boolean index (potentially making a copy of a rather large DataFrame):

```py
df_train[df_train['Pclass'] == 1]

   Age  Pclass  Other Col  Other Col2
0   10       1          1           7
2   12       1          3           9
5   15       1          6          12
```

then select the resulting Age column from this subset of rows (potentially making another copy of the Series `'Age'`):

```py
df_train[df_train['Pclass'] == 1]['Age']

0    10
2    12
5    15
Name: Age, dtype: int64
```

This can be expensive as we need to create a subset of many unneeded columns when filtering rows, then pick only one column.

---

However, the best approach is to use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) instead to select from both dimensions at once:

```py
df_train.loc[df_train['Pclass'] == 1, 'Age']

0    10
2    12
5    15
Name: Age, dtype: int64
```

This prevents needing to create multiple copies when selecting both rows and columns.