# Does slicing by columns before selecting indeces with .loc perform significantly faster in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, large-data

I'm wondering whether indexing by columns perform differently (and whether this performance difference is significant), particularly when using `.loc` for lookups with lists.

Consider the scenario where we have a large DataFrame of size RxC (where R=rows, C=columns) and R>>C (substantially more rows than columns).

I'm wondering whether there's a speed difference between doing:

1. `large_df['col_1'].loc['list_of_indeces']`

vs.

2. `large_df.loc['list_of_indeces']['col_1']`

The rationale is that maybe option 1) will work better since, we are slicing the DataFrame to only the columns of interest before using `.loc` for the lookup. I guess that depending on how this is implemented under the hood, they might perform similarly, or maybe 1) could be either more memory efficient or computationally efficient.

Comment: `.loc[rows, columns]` should be faster. your heading is a bit confusing though, as slicing is usually `['col1': 'col10']`

Comment: @sammywemmy is correct both of these are incorrect uses of `loc` the core purpose of the Indexer is to _prevent_ this kind of chained assignment. Having said this, selecting performance will depend on which direction selects less diverse data on the first pass. The faster is _usually_ selecting columns then rows since columns are guaranteed to share dtypes where row slices will cover many dtypes and have many different BlocManagers. Related: [What is the difference between using df\[col\]\[mask\] and df\[mask\]\[col\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70076481/15497888)